# BuildTools.jar Minecraft server install not working

Tags: java, compiler-errors, minecraft, git-bash

In setting up my server, I am also looking at creating some of my own plugins. When I go to install BuildTools.jar using `java -jar BuildTools.jar` I get the following error:

```
Poyda@MY-COMPUTER-NAME MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Testing Folder/New folder
$ java -jar BuildTools.jar
Loading BuildTools version: git-BuildTools-2652406-111 (#111)
Java Version: Java 8
Current Path: C:\Users\Poyda\Desktop\Testing Folder\New folder\.
git version 2.25.0.windows.1
IPoydaI
56775882+IPoydaI@users.noreply.github.com
Attempting to build version: 'latest' use --rev <version> to override
Could not get version latest does it exist? Try another version or use 'latest'
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.get(Builder.java:668)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.main(Builder.java:316)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:40)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        ... 22 more
```

This is on Windows, in "Git Bash for Windows"...

I have never used java before, if someone could please tell me whats going wrong?

Comment: Check if you are using valid certificate.

Comment: How do i do that? like i said, ima noob...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically ended up I needed to disable my company Internet Protection Policies, and then installed no worries...don't know if this will help whoever up-voted my question though.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, try and upgrade to [Git for Windows 2.25.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.25.1.windows.1) (the 2.25.0 had a curl issue which might have an impact here)

Since the error message is about a certificate chain missing in the JDK keystore, it depends on what server the jar is attempting to contact.

If upgrading Git does not help, you need to add where that jar is coming from.
For instance, if it is about spigot, [read this thread](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/errors-building-spigot-read-this-first.36985/page-2), which points out to a BuildTools.jar coming from [`hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/BuildTools/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/BuildTools.jar`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/BuildTools/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/BuildTools.jar).